# accessing local webserver on lan with simaple name like http://example.intranet.com

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

I have a small network , with one ubuntu 12.04 (on which I am trying to host a local intranet website) server machine and several desktops . What I essentially want is to access the deployed pages on the server with simple names like http://example.intranet.com , within the network. How can In accomplish it?...

I have apache tomcat server installed on the server machine.

Regards

Avanindra

Comment: This would probably be better off at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: is there a way to move the thread there?..

Comment: That is up to the admins.

Answer (score 2):

You need to deploy DNS server which will serve all clients on local network or create record in

**/etc/hosts** on all client PCs with following content:

```
192.168.1.10    example.intranet.com
```

Note that 192.168.1.10 is IP of host where web server is running on.

Depends on your web server configuration, you may also setup virtual host config.

**UPDATE:**

As first, try to ping webserver using it's name from client machine.If you receive answer with real IP first step is done.Next step is check your web server configuration.

AFAIK Tomcat is running by default on 8080 (and maybe bound just to 127.0.0.1) so you need to check server.xml and setup connector accordingly.

Also note that ports below 1024 can be bound only by root, so you should setup reverse proxy using Apache and mod_proxy_ajp

Comment: I have done that , I have added an entry to /etc/hosts. I am using dnsmasq for DNS Server , which is also installed on the same server. 

What should be my next step?...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up an DNS Server / Forwarder and the clients should use it as their default DNS Server.

In Ubuntu you can easily use p.e. dnsmasq
Then check out the config file /etc/dnsmasq.conf and set

```
server=/intranet/192.168.0.1
```

replace 192.168.0.1 with your server IP address

Then all cients can access the apache webserver by typing 
`http://intranet`